# RStudio project with network path

Tags: r, directory, path, rstudio, working-directory

When trying to make a new Rproject I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Unexpected exception: rstudio_boost::filesystem::status:
>   Invalid function "//client/"

I have the feeling this has something to do with my working directory being a network location and the use of '\' instead of '/'.
The address of the folder I try to make a RProject in is something like this:

> \client\G$\somefolder\somefolder\some folder with spaces\some folder
>   with spaces

Does anyone have a workaround when working with such locations?

Comment: Did you try to map the network location as a drive?

Comment: I did not try this. In the end I solved the problem by downgrading to an earlier version of RStudio.

Comment: I have the same issue...